Module 'CssScopes' is not defined - Exploring Bolero F# with simple Hello World app -
Getting the following error when running the installed app at the commmand line:

C:\Users\kachri\Documents\tryBolero\HelloWorld>dotnet run --project src/HelloWorld.Server
C:\Users\kachri\Documents\tryBolero\HelloWorld\src\HelloWorld.Client\Main.fs(225,27): error FS0039: The value, namespac
e, type or module 'CssScopes' is not defined. [C:\Users\kachri\Documents\tryBolero\HelloWorld\src\HelloWorld.Client\Hel
loWorld.Client.fsproj]

This is the line its complaining about:
type MyApp() =
  inherit ProgramComponent<Model, Message>()

        override _.CssScope = CssScopes.MyApp

Followed steps to install Hello World app from https://fsbolero.io/docs/
What am I missing that the installed template application is expecting me to have ?
My understanding in reading on what CssScopes might be is that it is built by Bolero at compile and then would be available to reference.  I have not changed the application template so this should just work.

I had the same issue with the dotnet SDK version 8.0.403. Using 8.0.110 or 8.0.306 works for me.
If you end up having multiple SDK versions of dotnet installed (see dotnet --list-sdks) you must specify the version for your project by adding a  global.json next to your .sln project file.
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "8.0.110"
    }
}

